# concatenating dense layers with different activations

Tags: keras, concatenation, layer, activation

While concatenating the output from two fully connected layers, doesn it really make sense if the activations in the two dense layers are different?

```
inp1 = Input((10,))
inp2 = Input((8,))
out1 = Dense(32, activation='tanh')(inp1)
out2 = Dense(32, activation='sigmoid')(inp2)
combined = concatenate(out1, out2)
```

Comment: If the dimensions fit, the data will progress... In the case of tanh vs sigmoid, follow your concatenation with a max/avg pool to get the best from both... for example!

Answer (score 1):

It can make sense. In your case it seems as if you have two different networks in one model, as the different inputs lead to different outputs and don't share layers. 
In other cases you could concatenate the outputs of two dense layers with say a linear and a softmax activation function,which would lead to regression and classification outputs respectively.